# How do I require a module using node from the command line?

Tags: node.js

I'm using Mac OSX. I've installed node via Homebrew. I've installed my library ([MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)) via `npm install -g moment`.

When I type `node` in the command line, I get the NodeJS console, it looks like:

> >

Now, let's say I want to use the `moment` library. If I type:

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'moment'

How might I configure and `require` an external library using Node from the command line?

Comment: My flow is to be in a command line, running some code and exploring, then finding I need a module (moment is a great example if I find a date I need to process). Wouldn't it be awesome to require a module using an internet address, in the middle of using the command line? This is impractical as NPM is separate from node of course.

Comment: I've just found this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-from-url - I'll see if that might give me what I'm looking for! :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can execute the following:

```
npm install moment # module must be installed locally
node --require moment
```

And enter the following:

```
var moment = require('moment');
moment().format();
```

From the `man` page:

```
-r, --require          module to preload at startup
```

[According to the source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/13151aae1a5e6e22052efd1816cc35bc1aae377c/src/node.cc#L3328), it appears that `node --require` will not search for global modules in version 4.2.x and will not raise any errors if the module is installed globally and not locally.

Comment: I just realized I ran my code in a directory with `moment` installed locally, not globally. It looks like `--require` might not support global modules.

Comment: Aha! It has to be installed locally. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at the [node source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/13151aae1a5e6e22052efd1816cc35bc1aae377c/src/node.cc#L3328), it appears  only local modules are able to be required. Node does not check the global modules if the local search fails.

Comment: Im interest in automagically having the `moment` global available from the command-line require.. Given that you explicitly require in the script, I think the command-line option `--require moment` is redundant

Comment: the linked to source code (node.cc) seems to actually be using "local" in the sense of the scope of the variable, not local in the sense of package location (later on, the local array is copied to a global one).  The correct source link seems to be [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9dcc9b6a6b3b8ab40be91b2fdc6fdf514e48dcc3/lib/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js#L888) which sets the module search path for preloaded modules to the working directory

Comment: Also, for example, you can prepend `NODE_PATH=./lib node ...` (for example) if you're requiring a module that exists in your project.

Comment: The command `NODE_PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules node` seems to work for me, for modules installed globally with `npm install -g`. As far as I can tell, it's specifying `NODE_PATH` that is significant, and the `--require` seems redundant.